# C# Plugin for xCode 4.3

Tags: c#, xcode

I've got an algorithm in C# that I need to include in an Objective C solution using xCode IDE. Is there any viable way to port this C# method into xCode? I don't see much support for Cocoa Sharp.

Thank you for your consideration....

Comment: could you just re-implement the algorithm in objective c?

Comment: Sure that's possible, but man that would take some time; it's about 1000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a way to do this.  There is probably a hack you could do using mono, but I would highly advise against such convolution.